# How to map values to new column with upper and lower bounds

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dictionary

Given a dataframe with two columns that describe a record type and the phase it is in, what is the most pythonic way of assigning unique values to a new column based on the phase and type? For example:

```
d = {'type': ['a','b','c','a','b','c','a','b','c',], 'phase': [-10,3,2,1,-7,-3,-1,-5,4]}
df_ = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df_
```

[image]

Contrived example mappings with upper and lower bounds:

```
a_phase = {
('<', -9):0.001,
-9:0.010,
-8:0.022,
-7:0.026,
-6:0.092,
-5:0.091,
-4:0.082,
-3:0.121,
-2:0.060,
-1:0.105,
0:0.018,
1:0.092,
2:0.092,
3:0.092,
4:0.092,
('>',4):0.000,
}

b_phase = {
('<', -9):0.016,
-9:0.011,
-8:0.021,
-7:0.028,
-6:0.052,
-5:0.075,
-4:0.057,
-3:0.102,
-2:0.238,
-1:0.270,
0:0.034,
1:0.014,
2:0.061,
('>',2):0.000,
}

c_phase = {
('<', -9):0.016,
-9:0.016,
-8:0.011,
-7:0.010,
-6:0.038,
-5:0.015,
-4:0.099,
-3:0.117,
-2:0.216,
-1:0.213,
0:0.008,
1:0.008,
2:0.008,
('>',2):0.000,
}
```

I could just go about using a bunch of `np.where` clauses but that feels extremely inefficient so I wanted to reach out to the community and see if anyone has suggestions. I also realize I can't use logical operators `>` `<` as keys in my dictionary mappings, this is for representation purposes only.

The ideal output would look like:

[image]

Comment: Your `x_phase` objects are not valid python, please provide valid objects.

Comment: @mozway done -- i forgot you could set tuples as keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option could be to set up a nested dictionary and map the values per group, eventually using [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to bin the ranges. If you have many dictionaries that might not be very efficient.

Another option, if you change your dictionaries a bit would be to craft a DataFrame and use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html):

```
Inf = float('inf')

a_phase = {
-Inf:0.001,
-9:0.010,
-8:0.022,
-7:0.026,
-6:0.092,
-5:0.091,
-4:0.082,
-3:0.121,
-2:0.060,
-1:0.105,
0:0.018,
1:0.092,
2:0.092,
3:0.092,
4:0.092,
4.1:0.000,
}
b_phase = {
-Inf:0.016,
-9:0.011,
-8:0.021,
-7:0.028,
-6:0.052,
-5:0.075,
-4:0.057,
-3:0.102,
-2:0.238,
-1:0.270,
0:0.034,
1:0.014,
2:0.061,
2.1:0.000,
}
c_phase = {
-Inf:0.016,
-9:0.016,
-8:0.011,
-7:0.010,
-6:0.038,
-5:0.015,
-4:0.099,
-3:0.117,
-2:0.216,
-1:0.213,
0:0.008,
1:0.008,
2:0.008,
2.1:0.000,
}

ref = (pd.DataFrame({'a': a_phase, 'b': b_phase, 'c': c_phase})
         .melt(var_name='type', value_name='weight', ignore_index=False)
         .rename_axis('phase').reset_index()
         .sort_values(by='phase')
         .dropna(subset='weight')
       )

out = (pd.merge_asof(df_.reset_index()
                        .astype({'phase': 'float64'})
                        .sort_values(by='phase'),
                     ref, by='type', on='phase')#, direction='forward')
         .set_index('index').reindex(df_.index)
       )
```

Output:

```
  type  phase  weight
0    a  -10.0   0.001
1    b    3.0   0.000
2    c    2.0   0.008
3    a    1.0   0.092
4    b   -7.0   0.028
5    c   -3.0   0.117
6    a   -1.0   0.105
7    b   -5.0   0.075
8    c    4.0   0.000
```

Comment: I really like this solution, out of curiosity why wouldn't I set the upper bound to `Inf`?

Comment: Because it's not the upper bound, it's the lower bound of the upper interval ;)

Comment: Oh I think I understand after reading over the documentation on `merge_asof`. We can't set the upper bound to `Inf` because we are matching on closest keys "backwards". Correct?

Comment: Ah just saw your comment above, that makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

First modify dictioanries by tuples for less and more values:

```
a_phase = {
('<', -9):0.001,
-9:0.010,
-8:0.022,
-7:0.026,
-6:0.092,
-5:0.091,
-4:0.082,
-3:0.121,
-2:0.060,
-1:0.105,
0:0.018,
1:0.092,
2:0.092,
3:0.092,
4:0.092,
('>', 4):0.000,
}

b_phase = {
('<', -9):0.016,
-9:0.011,
-8:0.021,
-7:0.028,
-6:0.052,
-5:0.075,
-4:0.057,
-3:0.102,
-2:0.238,
-1:0.270,
0:0.034,
1:0.014,
2:0.061,
('>', 2):0.000,
}

c_phase = {
('<', -9):0.016,
-9:0.016,
-8:0.011,
-7:0.010,
-6:0.038,
-5:0.015,
-4:0.099,
-3:0.117,
-2:0.216,
-1:0.213,
0:0.008,
1:0.008,
2:0.008,
('>', 2):0.000,
}
```

Then create DataFrame by dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'a':a_phase,
      'b':b_phase,
      'c':c_phase}

df = pd.DataFrame(((k, *x) for k, v in d1.items() for x in v.items()),
                  columns=['type','phase','weight'])
```

And left join exact matched values, not matched less and greater ones:

```
df_ = df_.merge(df, how='left')
```

Processing only not matched values filled missing values, first exctract them:

```
mask = df_['weight'].isna()

df1 = (df[pd.to_numeric(df['phase'], errors='coerce').isna()]
            .assign(op=lambda x: x['phase'].str[0], phase=lambda x: x['phase'].str[1]))

print (df1)

   type  phase  weight op
0     a     -9   0.001  <
15    a      4   0.000  >
16    b     -9   0.016  <
29    b      2   0.000  >
30    c     -9   0.016  <
43    c      2   0.000  >
```

And then filter and merge by `type` for both, join togethter and assign to column `weight` filtered by mask:

```
s1 = (df_[mask].reset_index().merge(df1[df1['op'].eq('<')], how='left', on='type')
                .assign(weight = lambda x: x['weight_y'].where(x['phase_x'].lt(x['phase_y'])))
                .set_index('index')['weight'].dropna())

s2 = (df_[mask].reset_index().merge(df1[df1['op'].eq('>')], how='left', on='type')
                .assign(weight = lambda x: x['weight_y'].where(x['phase_x'].gt(x['phase_y'])))
                .set_index('index')['weight'].dropna())

df_.loc[mask, 'weight'] = pd.concat([s1, s2])
print (df_)
  type phase  weight
0    a   -10   0.001
1    b     3   0.000
2    c     2   0.008
3    a     1   0.092
4    b    -7   0.028
5    c    -3   0.117
6    a    -1   0.105
7    b    -5   0.075
8    c     4   0.000
```